# Is $X$ measurable w.r.t $X+Y$? That is $X \in \sigma(X+Y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, measurable-functions

Consider two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, where $Y$ is standard Gaussian noise. I am interested in analyzing $\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y]$. I know that

$\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y] = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx}$.

If $X$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{G}$, then $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}] = X$ almost surely.

Since $X$ and $X+Y$ are not independent, I was wondering if $X$ is measurable w.r.t the sigma algebra generated by $X+Y$? Is $X \in \sigma(X+Y)$?

I am having a hard time navigating conditional expectation. Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: In general, $X$ is not measurable with respect to $X+Y$. I am also doubtful of your expression for $\mathbb E[X\mid X+Y]$. Finally, one would never write 
"$X\in\sigma(X+Y)$" because $X$ is a measurable function while $\sigma(X+Y)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (a collection of sets).

Comment: @Math1000: It is actually pretty common notation, though technically an abuse, to write $X \in \mathcal{F}$ to mean "$X$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$".

Comment: I personally would never write that, and would always write "$X$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable". I think the abuse of notation is egregious, as it suggests that $X$ is an event instead of a random variable, and would be very confusing if say I came across it in a definition or a proof.

Comment: @Math1000 Yes you are right, but I have seen this notation in a lot of places. Strictly speaking, yes it would suggest $X$ is an event.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the general answer, but in the case where $X$ is also a standard normal random variable, the answer is no. Indeed, since $(X,X+Y)$ and $(Y,X+Y)$ have the same distribution, it follows that $\mathbb E\left[X\mid X+Y\right]=\mathbb E\left[Y\mid X+Y\right]$ hence $\mathbb E\left[X\mid X+Y\right]=(X+Y)/2$. 
If $X$ was $\sigma(X+Y)$-measurable, the equality $\mathbb E\left[X\mid X+Y\right]=X$ would hold which is not compatible with the previous one.

Comment: If there is even one case where $X$ is not measurable w.r.t $X+Y$ then I guess that rules out finding it out in general.
In my case, X is not standard normal. Thank you!